# What is the easiest way to get rid of spilled glitter?

Tags: cleaning, carpet

I was recently glitterbombed from a "friend" playing a prank on me. It got all over my carpet, my desk, and my room. I have tried sweeping glitter to no avail, tried vacuming to no avail (because the damn glitter keeps sticking onto the carpet).

Is there a simple way to get rid of spilled glitter?

Comment: How it can it be a duplicate if the glitter isn't on my skin?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it is not about the glitter it is about the surface it is on, cleaning skin and cleaning carpet and floor is to different topics.

Comment: I'm just curious, because this has become somewhat viral: Did you receive the glitter from [this site](https://shipyourenemiesglitter.com/)? If this question gets some good answers we could advertise this question by sending our enemies glitter, thus they probably search for a solution and find this question, ergo we get bunch of new visitors and we have a healthy beta... Tbh, I'm kidding, so please don't do this! Do this only if you really want to piss someone off.

Comment: @Alex There's a special place in hell for whoever came up with that...

Comment: @Alex All I know is that it came in a pretty pink envelope with, what I know understand, a very generic name (it was John Fulkerson, someone I had no idea who he was), but I opened it and bam, it sprayed open all over my carpet and desk.

Comment: Is there any way to report those people who are too lazy to read questions before marking them as duplicates? It gets really annoying to try and explain to them just because they wouldn't read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a lint roller -- one of those rolls of adhesive tape with a handle on it, where the tape's adhesive is on the outside. I use that for oddball cleanups on carpet sometimes.

[image]

You'll go through a lot of layers of the tape, and probably several lint rollers. But it probably works better than the air suction of a vacuum.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do several things. If you do all of this maybe the glitter will be removed:

1. Vacuum it with powerful vacuum cleaner (maybe several times)
2. Take the carpet outdoors and beat it with carpet beater (then you can vacuum it again)
3. Wash the carpet with pressure washer

Answer (score 2):

If its a fitted carpet, hopefully short piled and not long, the only answer is a more powerful vacuum cleaner, as suggested already in Vladiz's answer. If its not fitted, then his suggestion of beating it thoroughly outdoors should get the majority of it out.

Not sure about 'pressure washer' - a dedicated carpet washer might work, but the ones made for home users often don't suck loose stuff (never mind dirt) up as well as a good vacuum cleaner, so you'd probably need a professional carpet cleaning company to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I Agree with other posts use a powerful vacuum cleaner to get it out of the carpet. This to say a standard vacuum cleaner is not likely to do the job, so you may need alternates.

A shop vacuum would work well. They have high suction with a variety of attachments that well may work to get the glitter.

A carpet cleaning machine. Handheld or consumer models all offer a higher suction then a conventional vacuum cleaner and can be bought from about 40 USD for a handheld to several hundred USD for a stand up model. If just air does not pull the glitter out you can try the detergent and water, which gives you even more agitation and chemical to release the glitter from your carpet.

Rent a carpet cleaner. Available at many grocery stores, hardware stores and rental yards, check your local listings. Cheaper then buying and the machines are generally a little more powerful then buying.

And last resort is a professional carpet cleaner whom have very powerful equipment and can get the job done.

I see as I write that you accepted lint roller as the answer, if that works that is great.

Comment: I tried a vacumn but unfortunately mines is pretty bad and it didn't really do much on the carpet, but it worked well on t he desk. The lint roller helped solve the carpet issue, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In my country (Italy) there is a [famous vacuum cleaner company](http://www.kirby.com/) which provides demonstrations of their really (really really) powerful vacuum cleaner.
All you have to do is call them and ask for a free demonstration in cleaning your carpet.

Usually they demonstrate the product on your mattress, and you don't really want to know what they can clean from it (judging from the quantity of dead cells on the mattress you should be vanished by now).

Answer (score 0):

In your question you said that you can't vacuum because the glitter is sticking. One way to help get the glitter unstuck is to use rubbing alcohol with a towel on the glitter. This will get up some of the glitter and help loosen the bonds of the rest. Now it will be easier to vacuum. I would also recommend using the part of the vacuum that you hold with your hand because a smaller suction area is more powerful. You can also use masking tape. Wrap the masking tape around your hand so that the sticky side is facing out. Now you'll have to get down on the ground and use the tape to get up as much glitter as possible. This combination of vacuuming and tape can be very effective.

Answer (score -1):

You could  get it up by washing it in a washing machine. If it's a fitted carpet than use THE MOST POWERFUL VACCUM YOU CAN FIND!! Also you should be glad it wasn't on concrete floors. That's a MAJOR PAIN IN THE ASS!!!! P.S I know how you feel. It's super annoying to clean the damn glitter!!!!!